# How is article the used to describe relations?

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-articles, grammaticality

Which sentence is **correct**?: "I am **the** son of Mary" or " I **am son** of Mary"?

Comment: How many sons does Mary have? Potentially neither sentence is correct.

Comment: " I am the son of Mary" is correct.  You can also say 'I am Mary's son', but I suspect you know that already.

Comment: _Son of X_ without an article is only used in the historical context. When hereditary surnames did not exist, a man might be identified as 'John son of William'.